# MS Dynamics CRM and Sharepoint integration issues

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, integration

I've CRM server and 2 Sharepoint servers, one for internal operators among several agencies to manage customers' documents and applications, one for web-portal for public users to track changes e.g. of their applications, and the CRM defines business models and business processes.

What should I consider in terms of integration of these systems? 
What kind of integration toolkit I need to use?
Should I use an External Connector for these purposes?

Sultan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a pretty big article on what you need to do to get it all hooked together [here](http://www.ryanonrails.com/2011/02/25/hooking-crm-2011-and-share-point-2010-together/). I did it on just 1 VM, however going across servers shouldn't be much more work.

However essentially what it boils down to is installing the list control in SharePoint, setting up a SharePoint site in CRM2011 and then allowing the entities in CRM to have document management enabled.

Comment: Been trying your guide ). Really nice job @RyanonRails thanks.

Comment: how to make possible creation of CRM entities from Sharepoint?

Comment: @sultan You'll need to create the entity in CRM2011 (under customizations, or a specific solution). Settings -> Solutions -> Create Solution -> Open solution -> Click Entities -> New. Once you've created the entity then you can follow the directions that I did for the Account Entity in the tutorial.